# Excelの特定の列、行の値の取得方法について教えてください

Tags: excel, vb.net, rpa

表題の件について、
テーブルがあるとして、
その表の中に、何行か値があります。
欲しいのは、A列ではなく、B列、２行目以降のセルの値です。

For Eachでループをかけ、行に値がなくなったら終了。
という繰り返しで、

```
Dim dtRows As datatable 
For each dtRows in Keywords.row
   String.isNullofEmpty(dtRows.item("値").ToString())
Next
```

"値" = B2 セルになります。
上記ループで取得する方法を教えていただければと思います。

Answer (score 1):

すみません。

自己解決しました。

コード上の問題ではなく、
Excelのパラメータ取得する、対象のシートが違っていました。